# Should a comma be used after although?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions

When is a comma after although correct and when it is incorrect? Which of these two sentences is correct?

"This could work as a great topic for a book, although I could also use it as a topic for a short newspaper article."

"This could work as a great topic for a book, although, I could also use it as a topic for a short newspaper article."

Please don't bother with any other grammatical errors in these sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I struggle to think of a situation where a comma after 'although' is appropriate, except in screenplays (and only for dramatic effect). There is another word, though, which is on the tip of my tongue.